# Assign IAM roles to GSuite admin console groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-iam

There is plenty of documentation explaining how to assign IAM roles in GCP to all members of a GSuite organization, but none discuss any more granular permissioning.

Is it possible to create an admin console group in GSuite and then apply specific IAM roles to all members of that group in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

yes this works the same way you would assign to a user. The GSuite group is represented by an email address. Simply assign the roles/permissions you want to that group email and all users within that group will receive them.